# Resolve SWD Communication Failure

Tags: microcontroller, jtag, keil, swd, stm32f3

I have developed a board with stm32f373VB and I'm trying to test the PCB with ULINK/2 and uVision V4.70.0. I got a SWD Communication Failure, and I can't program the uC.

[image]

And here is the layout:

[image]

Any ideas what could be wrong, or where to look for the problem?

Comment: I made it work, by putting the jumper within the ULink2 to 3.3 V. This is very weird, because for the previous prototype with stm32f373R8 lqfp 64, this was not necessary as well as for one board with stm32f105. How could that be?

Comment: Also I have another problem: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/185860/stm32f373vb-produces-a-short-circuit-after-some-time

Answer (score 1):

The jumper setting inside the ULINK2 is best described here:
http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/ulink2/ulink2_hw_jumpers.htm

The "SWD Communication Failure" is often caused by a connection or power issue. It seems that the board did not supply power to the JTAG port, so the ULINK debugger had to.

Comment: But the board supplies power to the JTAG port as you can see from the schematic. Also I have measured the 3.3V supply voltage on the JTAG port (without connecting the JTAG cable to it of course).